# Retrieve VarBinary Data from SQL and Save the image/file

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

When I use the SQL statement

```
SELECT File_Data 
FROM Attachments 
WHERE UserID = '12345' AND FileNames = 'testing1.jpg'
```

the image downloads and looks great. But if I put in a stored procedure it creates the file of `testing1.jpg` in my folder called `C:\Testing\` but it is not writing the data in the image and it will not display correctly. Below is what I have to call the stored procedure and to write it up. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?

For testing purpose:

- strfilename = `testing1.jpg`
- userid = `12345`

Code:

```
protected void LoadFiles(string strfilename, int userid)
{
    string fullname = strfilename;

    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(conn_string))
    {
        cn.Open();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GET_ATTACHMENT", cn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;                   

            SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@FileName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255);
            p1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            p1.Value = strfilename;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);

            SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("@User_ID", SqlDbType.Int);
            p2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            p2.Value = userid;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);

            // Tried using this statement but it did not work. //
            SqlParameter pSub = new SqlParameter("@File_Data", SqlDbType.VarBinary);
            pSub.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(pSub);
            Response.Write(pSub);

            // *** *** ///                    
            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
            {
                if (dr.Read())
                {

                  // For some reason the data being returned is blank
                  // When I run it in SQL I get data being returned.

                    byte[] fileData = (byte[])dr.GetValue(0);

                    using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream("C:\\Testing\\" + (fullname), System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        using (System.IO.BinaryWriter bw = new System.IO.BinaryWriter(fs))
                        {
                            bw.Write(fileData);
                            bw.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }

                dr.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SQL Server stored procedure:

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_ATTACHMENT]
     @User_ID int,
     @FileName nvarchar(250)
 AS
 BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @FileData varbinary(max)

    Set @FileData = (SELECT File_Data FROM Attachments 
       WHERE UserID = @User_ID and 
       FileNames = @FileName);

    SELECT @FileData

END
```

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

Set a break point at `byte[] fileData = (byte[])dr.GetValue(0);` to see if any data is returned before writing it to the file.

Use `CommandBehavior.Default`

When using `CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess` try using [GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of SqlDataReader.

As the last resort, change your SP to return User_ID, just to check if anything is returned.

Comment: The data returned is: System.Byte[]

Comment: The values being returned is blank.

Comment: @mrmcg Even when using `CommandBehavior.Default`? Can you run any stored procedure then?

Comment: Yes. It will run but no data is coming through.